# Covering number estimates for Hölder balls

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, packing-and-covering

Let $\alpha \in (0,1]$, $r>0$ and $L>0$, and positive intwgers $n$ and $m$.  The Arzela-Ascoli Theorem guarantees that the set $X(\alpha,L,r)$ of $f:[-1,1]^n\rightarrow [-r,r]^m$ with $\alpha$-Hölder norm at-most $L$ is compact in $C([-1,1]^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ for the *topology of uniform convergence*.  Therefore, in particular, $X(\alpha,L,r)$ must be totally-bounded.

Are there known *lower* bounds on the [$\varepsilon$-extendal covering number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_number) of $X(\alpha,L,r)$; i.e.: the number of uniform $\varepsilon$-balls required to cover $X(\alpha,L)$?

Comment: do you have any regime in mind? e.g. fixed $\alpha$ and large $L$, or fixed $L$ and small $\alpha$?

Comment: In $1d$ take consecutive points $\{ x_1, \dots, x_n \}$  in $[-1,1]$ whose distance are of order $L^{-1} \epsilon^{1/\alpha}$ so that $n \approx L \epsilon^{-1/\alpha}$. If $|f| \leq 1$ subdivide $[-1,1]$ with points $\{y_1, \dots, y_m\}$ such that $y_{i+1}-y_i \leq \epsilon$ so that $m \approx \epsilon^{-1}$. Given a map $\theta: \{x_1, \dots ,x_n\} \to \{y_1, \dots, y_m\}$ consider $F_\theta$ the set of all functions in $X(\alpha, L)$ with $|f| \leq 1$ such that $f(x_i) \in [\theta(x_i)-\epsilon, \theta(x_i)+\epsilon]$.

Comment: These sets are at most $m^n$ and have diameter of order $\epsilon$. This gives a rough estimate in 1d. In several variables it should be similar

Comment: This type of result is standard in the statistical literature. See e.g. van der Vaart, Wellner, Empirical Process Theory, 1998, chapter 2, where covering numbers are provided for higher-order smoothness classes as well. I believe they take $m=1$ but I imagine their proof can be adapted.

Comment: $\log N(\varepsilon,X(\alpha,L), \|\cdot\|_{\infty}) \approx (1/\varepsilon)^{\frac{n}{\alpha }}$ is what they give for $m=1$ (Theorem 2.7.1. in the reference I mentioned).

Comment: For the case of general $m$, note that the i-th component function $f_i$ of a vector-valued Holder function $f$ is Holder as well. This follows since $|f_i(x) - f_i(y)| \leq \sup_i |f_i(x) - f_i(y)| \leq \|f(x) - f(y)\|_2 \leq \sqrt{m} \sup_i \|f_i(x) - f_i(y)\|$. Thus, we can $\varepsilon$-cover the space of each $ith$ component functions with $\exp((1/\varepsilon)^{n/\alpha})$ balls. Such a cover for each $i$ implies a cover for vector-valued Holder functions with at most $\Big[\exp((1/\varepsilon)^{n/\alpha})\Big]^m$ balls.

Comment: Thus, $\log N(\varepsilon, X(\alpha, L), \|\cdot\|_{\infty}) \lessapprox m(1/\varepsilon)^{n/\alpha}$ in the general case.

Comment: Entropies of functional compact sets were studied a lot. (See, for example, https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-64.1.153 and references.) For Sobolev space the best results are due to Birman and Solomyak. But I believe Holder functions in max-norm should be easier and known for a longer time.

Comment: Thank you to everyone.  Each of these are extremely helpful comments/answers.

Comment: To have the set $X(alpha,L)$ compact you should bound the set of values, for example, that all functions in $X(\alpha,L)$ take value in the segment $[-L,L]$.

Comment: @TarasBanakh edited.  I  think by packing the image with small balls, and combining lower bounds for the packing number of $\alpha$-Holder maps into sufficiently small intervals, one could get a descent lower bound.