# Covering number $C^k$-balls in $C(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, metric-spaces, packing-and-covering, smoothness, lipschitz-spaces

Fix a positive integer $n$ and and an non-negative integer $k$.  The Arzela-Ascoli theorem guarantees that for a given positive integer $k$ and a given $L>0$ the set
$$
Ball_{C^{k,1}([0,1]^n)}(0,L)
:=
\{f\in C(\mathbb{R}^n):\,\|f\|_{C^{k,1}}\leq L\}
,
$$
is compact in $C([0,1]^n)$ for the topology of uniform convergence on compacts.  Furthermore, by virtue of the inclusion $Ball_{C^{k,1}([0,1]^n)}(0,L)\subseteq Ball_{C^{0,1}(\mathbb{R}^n)}(0,L)$ and the metric entropy estimates of $Ball_{C^{0,1}(\mathbb{R}^n)}(0,L)$ we know that $Ball_{C^{k,1}(\mathbb{R}^n)}(0,L)$ has [$\epsilon$-covering number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_number) at-most
$$
\epsilon \propto \epsilon^{-n}.
$$

However, if $k>0$ then we should be able to do much better.  *Does any one know where to find tight covering number estimates for $Ball_{C^{k,1}([0,1]^n)}(0,L)$ for there case of general $k$?*

I should note that, the case where $k=0$ is addressed in these MO posts [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397935/covering-number-estimates-for-h%C3%B6lder-balls) and [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301603/covering-number-of-lipschitz-functions); but what about the general case?

---

I'm also curious about the analogous question in $L^1$, with the $C^{k,1}$ norm replaced by the Sobolev norm $W^{k}$.