# Covering/Bracketing number of monotone functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with uniformly bounded derivatives

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, entropy, packing-and-covering, machine-learning, learning-theory

I am interested in the $\| \cdot \|_{\infty}$-norm bracketing number or covering number of some collection of distribution functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $\mathcal{F}$ consist of all distribution functions on $\mathbb{R}$. There is an existing result (Thm 2.7.5, [van der Vaart and Wellner, 1996](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-2545-2)) on the $L_r(Q)$-norm bracketing number: For any $1 \leq r<\infty$ and any probability measure $Q$, there exists a constant $K$ depending only on $r$ that
$$
\log N_{[]}(\varepsilon, \mathcal{F}, L_r(Q) ) \leq K \frac{1}{\varepsilon}.
$$
However, using $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$-norm, the result does not hold. In fact, $N_{[]}(\varepsilon, \mathcal{F}, \|\cdot\|_{\infty}) = \infty$ for $\varepsilon<1/2$.

To have a nontrivial upper bound, if possible, I consider
$$
\mathcal{F}_s = \{ F \in \mathcal{F} : f \text{ is $m$-times continuously differentible, }  \|f\|_{C^m} \leq 1 \}
$$
where $\|f\|_{C^m} := \sum_{j=0}^m \|f^{(j)} \|_{\infty} $.

My questions is, what do we know about the covering number or bracketing number, under $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ norm, of such $\mathcal{F}_s$? Are they finite? If finite, is there any nontrivial upper bound?

I am aware of the results in Chapter 2.7 of [van der Vaart and Wellner (1996)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-2545-2). However, none of them is suitable, since I need the functions to have unbounded domain, and to be covered or bracketed in the supremum norm. [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301603/covering-number-of-lipschitz-functions?noredirect=1&lq=1) appears to be relevant, but it only assumes Lipschitz continuity, and I couldn't obtain finiteness using Lemma 6 in the [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7944658) mentioned therein.