# Packing number of Lipschitz functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, packing-and-covering, learning-theory, machine-learning

For some $L>0$ say ${\cal L}$ is the space of all $L-$Lipschitz functions mapping $(X,\rho) \rightarrow [0,1]$ where $(X,\rho)$ is a metric space.

- For any $\alpha >0$ do we know of a lowerbound on the $\alpha-$packing number of ${\cal L}$ assuming boundedness (or even compactness) of $(X,\rho)$?

---

On the function space I am assuming a a pseudo metric which is defined as follows : i.e for any $2$ functions $f$ and $g$ we have, the distance between them defined as, $d(f,g) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \vert f(x_i) - g(x_i) \vert$ for some choice of $n$ points $\{ x_1,..,x_n\}$ in the common domain of the functions i.e $X$.

Comment: No. Packing number and covering number are roughly of the same order of magnitude but they are not the same things. Though a lowerbound on the covering number will imply a lowerbound on the packing number at a different scale.

Comment: Maybe "$\alpha$-packing number"=maximum number of disjoint balls of radius $\alpha$?

Comment: Yes. Typically one is doing these under a "pesudo-metric" whereby some $n$ points in the domain has been chosen and one defines the distance between two functions $f$ and $g$ as, $d(f,g) := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \vert f(x_i) - g(x_i) \vert$

Comment: You have to tell us what the metric on $\mathcal{L}$ is before this is a meaningful question.

Comment: I mentioned the pseudo-metric in the comment just above yours.

Comment: I put in the details into the question!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the metric space $(X,\rho)$ has $\alpha$-packing numbers $M(\alpha)$. Then the function class $\mathcal{L}$ has $\gamma$-fat shattering dimension $M(2\gamma/L)$ --- see here
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6867374/
for the relevant definitions as well as a proof of this claim (Theorem 1).

The fat-shattering estimate implies an upper bound on the $\alpha$-packing numbers of $\mathcal{L}$: these are at most
$$ \left(\frac2\alpha\right)^{K M(c\alpha/L)} $$
for universal constants $K,c>0$; see Theorerm 2.18 in Mendelson's "A few notes on Statistical Learning Theory",
https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/281B-spring04/readings/mendelson.ps

A lower bound bound of $(c'/\alpha)^{M(c''\alpha/L)}$ follows from the discussion in this question,
[metric entropy for Lipschitz functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154427/metric-entropy-for-lipschitz-functions)
--- since the $L_\infty$ covering numbers always majorize the $L_1$ ones.