# Metric entropy of the space of Lipschitz functions between two metric spaces

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry

This question is on the same line as this older one [metric entropy for Lipschitz functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154427/metric-entropy-for-lipschitz-functions).

I would like to know if there is a reference for bounds of the covering numbers $\mathcal N(\mathsf{Lip}_L(X,Y), \epsilon, ||\cdot||_\infty)$, where $(X,d_X), (Y,d_Y)$ are metric spaces.

I'm using the usual notation in which $\mathsf{Lip}_L$ denotes the space of $L$-Lipschitz functions, and $||f-g||_\infty:=\sup_{x\in X} d_Y(f(x),g(x))$.

I'd like to know an upper bound for the above covering number, in terms of covering numbers $\mathcal N(X,L/\epsilon, d_X)$ and $\mathcal N(Y, \epsilon, d_Y)$ or some related quantities. This is due to Kolmogorov-Tikhomirov for the case $X$ is centralizable and $Y$ is an interval of the reals, but what about other nice doubling $Y$'s?

The proof of this type of bounds would not be that much different than the original Kolmogorov-Tikhomirov proof, but how could it be that nobody wrote it so far? I could not find any paper discussing it, maybe I'm using the wrong keywords in Google Scholar.

What would be good keywords? Or is there a problem, due to which the case of general metric space targets $Y$ is very complicated? Any indications would be highly appreciated!

**Edit**

The definition Kolmogorov-Tikhomirov use for covering is "covering by sets of diameter at most 2r" and the centralizability condition allows to pass to "covering by r-balls", and then most of the proof strategy proceeds by using r-balls. Thus when using coverings by balls, the original proof is sufficient. I'm guessing that since most application are based on r-ball covers, the covering using general sets is out of the radar of most of the community.

Comment: This could be empty; see the bottom of page 6 for an example: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2304.12231.pdf

Comment: Sorry, what could be empty? And what would be the number of the example in the preprint you link?

Comment: There could be no lipschitz functions between these spaces; the example is in the paragraph at the very last line of page 6.